# Is it possible to specify the data type of an Oracle 8i pseudocolumn when Selecting from Dual

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes, oracle8i

In Oracle, it is possible to generate pseudo-colums and "pseudo-tables" (not sure if that is an official term) on the fly like this:

```
(SELECT 'abc' AS pseudo_col_1,  123 AS pseudo_col_2 FROM dual) pseudo_table
```

I am looking to do the same, while specifying the datatype of `pseudo_col_1` and/or `pseudo_col_2`.
The following seems to work in Oracle 11g, where `pseudo_col_2` is specified as a CLOB datatype :

```
(SELECT 'abc' AS pseudo_col_1,  TO_CLOB(123) AS pseudo_col_2 FROM dual) pseudo_table
```

However, I need to achieve the same result on *Oracle 8i*, which has no TO_CLOB function.

Disclaimer: I know 8i is outdated, no need to comment on that aspect as I have *zero* control over this, sadly.

Comment: I'm not sure CLOB support was as mature in 8 as it is now. Why do you need to explicitly change the datatype?

Comment: I'm actually not looking to change the datatype, but to specify the datatype at the time the pseudocolumn is "generated", akin to how you explicitly declare a variable's type in C and other languages. Researching the doc further however, the `DUAL` table contains a single `VARCHAR2` columns. So I guess whatever pseudocolumn I create based on `DUAL` would remain a `VARCHAR2` type unless, as you mention, I "explicity change the datatype" which is obviously what I was doing by using `TO_CLOB`.

Comment: Is there any way to generate a pseudo-table / pseudo-columns from scratch, or from a table _other_ than `DUAL` which would contain datatypes other than `DUAL`'s `VARCHAR2` ?

Comment: The datatype of the column in the `dual` table doesn't matter to your query results. You can do `select 1 as a from dual` and get a number column. Maybe it would help if you explained why you're doing this, though Gordon Linoff's answer below probably works.

Answer (score 1):

You can `cast()` to the type you want:

```
SELECT cast('abc' as varchar2(255)) AS pseudo_col_1,
       cast(123 as decimal(10, 2)) AS pseudo_col_2
FROM dual;
```

Comment: You can't cast to CLOB though.

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . It didn't specify CLOB when I answered.  Interesting.

Comment: Sorry, did not specify CLOB in the question title, however it is specified in the body of the question. In any case, thank you for you answer. CAST could be a solution in later releases.